# location.hash disappears immediately

Tags: jquery

I'm building a live search + filter method, and I've noticed when I use that method (it's an example) that hash after it shows in the URL - it is immediately being removed. If I move that hash set to e.g. button's click method it works fine. Why ?

```
$('.menu-link').click(function () {            
        window.location.hash = 'search-container';
});
```

Comment: Are you going to a new page without realizing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's disappearing because your link is being followed, causing the location to be changed to the `href` of the `a`.  If you add a `return false;` to the end of your click handler, then the location won't change.

Comment: @Jacob ... THANK YOU. THANK YOU. THANK YOU. I was losing my mind trying to figure this out as well.

Comment: This behavior seems completely inconsistent between browsers. I didn't have a return for a hybrid mobile app, and it works for iOS 6/7, and Android 2.3 - 4.3. On 4.4, it caused problems, unless you called the evaluateJavascript function instead of loadUrl. Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function (event) {     
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = 'search-container';
});
```

Comment: nice approach, I'll try it. Thanks