# location.hash and the page is refreshing unlimited number of times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

after changing the `location.hash` ([location.hash disappears immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315311/location-hash-disappears-immediately)) if I refresh the whole page, it is being refreshed unlimited number of times. Why ?

Comment: It's all about the framework you are using... What is it? Did you developed the hole application?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: Can you show an URL example and a list of your routes?

Comment: `localhost:39217/BST/#search-container&t=j&c=147` the `Global.asax` default file is not changed

Comment: ...and I see that only once the Controller's action is being invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commented the script lint to the `MicrosoftAjax.js` the problem has gone.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316248/microsoftajax-js-causes-an-infinite-page-refreshing) I hope to get some more details 'why'.