# MicrosoftAjax.js causes an infinite page refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, microsoft-ajax

according to my question ([location.hash and the page is refreshing unlimited number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315678/location-hash-and-the-page-is-refreshing-unlimited-number-of-times)) I'm wondering, why - If I have a hash in the URL and included the `MicrosoftAjax.js` script - if I refresh the page, it is refreshing all the time. Any ideas ?

---

Here's the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111848/106616